# How to get caught exceptions of my application in the Glassfish 2.1 server log?

Tags: logging, glassfish, ejb, weblogic8.x

We have ported an EJB application  from BEA Weblogic 8.1 to Glassfish 2.1.
The client is accessing the server through RMI, no web client.

In Weblogic exceptions were logged automatically to server.log, even when they are catched and rethrown to the client.

In Glassfish with default configuration we can't see them in server.log.

How can I get the same behavior as with Weblogic?

Comment: what type of logging was used in weblogic (log4j, jul, etc.)?

Comment: @cmutt78 We used a proprietary logging framework, removing it solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish 2.1 logs via java.util.logging. Logging content, by default, is collected in

```
[Glassfish root]/domains/[domain name]/logs/server.log
```

For configuring j.u.l, find the `logging.properties` file in the JRE that is used to run Glassfish (in the lib directory), set your topics' (loggers') levels to desired granularity.

Note: that worked for me for an application using Apache Commons Logging, running on Glassfish.